# MS Word interop behavior

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I am working on a Windows app that uses MS Word interop to generate reports.  Environment is Windows 8.1 64-bit, Visual Studio 2013, Word 2013; the app is written in C#.  I'm experiencing unpredictable behavior with Word; sometimes it declines to process basic commands (ie SaveAs) and returns the error "Call was rejected by callee. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010001 (RPC_E_CALL_REJECTED))".  Typically I close the instance of Word, re-run the application and things work fine.  Of course I'm concerned about using this app in a production environment.

Here is the outline of how I'm using Word from C#:

```
word = new Application(); word.Visible = true;
doc = word.Documents.Add(docTemplatePath);
try { File.Delete(docPath); } catch { }
doc.SaveAs2(docPath);
// Populate the doc
doc.Save(); word.Quit(); Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(word);
```

Any ideas or experience on this is much appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps Word is busy doing something and cannot process the command.

Comment: There are a *lot* of google hits when you simply paste the error message into the search box.  You *must* show some evidence for why the workarounds recommended before do not work for you.

Comment: http://blogs.artinsoft.net/Mrojas/archive/2012/09/28/Office-Interop-and-Call-was-rejected-by-callee.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the blog refernce Hans - it appears that setting the `visible` property of the word instance to false makes things work reliably.  I'll do further testing and report back.

Comment: I'd suggest you to consider using open XML SDK, you don't even need to have office installed on your machine. [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854(v=office.15).aspx)